# Changing line in file based on previous lines - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Relatively new to python, trying to figure out the most general and readable way to attack this problem. Execution speed wouldn't be bad either, but its a secondary concern.

I have an input file for another program that I need to edit automatically. The format is similar to the following:

```
---Thousands of lines that can be ignored---
&Brand: Ford
&Define Class
&Model: Sedan
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&25000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&14

&Brand: Honda
&Define Class
&Model: Sedan
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&22000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&17
&Model: SUV
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&35000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&7
---Thousands of lines that can be ignored---
```

My code needs to automatically change the numerical parameters. The trouble I'm having is that I'm not just matching a single condition and changing a line, I'm matching unique combinations of non-unique lines (Parameter: Cost appears three times, twice under Model: Sedan and twice under Brand: Honda, but only once under both of those conditions).

Right I'm storing the new parameters in a nested dictionary, like:

```
params = {'Ford': {'Sedan': {'Cost': 17000, 'Stock': 43}}, 'Honda':{'Sedan': {'Cost': 19000, 'Stock': 12}, {'Truck': {'Cost': 33000, 'Stock': 5}}}
```

In this way I can do `for brand in params.keys()` and then `for model in params[brand].keys()` and so on.

I have the basics of opening, closing, and modifying files down, it is identifying the correct lines to be modified that I'm having trouble with. Thanks for any help.

Ex:
For the above sample dictionary, the ideal output would be:

```
---Thousands of lines that can be ignored---
&Brand: Ford
&Define Class
&Model: Sedan
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&17000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&43

&Brand: Honda
&Define Class
&Model: Sedan
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&19000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&12
&Model: SUV
&Parameter: Cost
&Dollars
&33000
&Parameter: Stock
&Quantity
&5
---Thousands of lines that can be ignored---
```

Comment: Please provide us testcases - given your file show us what expected output should look like.

Comment: ummm `line.startswith("&")` ?

Comment: @Nsh Just added a sample output based on the same parameter dictionary I defined. As you can see, it is only the numerical parameters that should be edited, the rest of the file should structured identically.

Comment: @Joran Unfortunately most of the lines in the many-thousand line file begin with the same character, and I'm only attempting to change the numerical parameters based on their headings and subheadings.

Comment: not solving your problem but you have one curly bracket too many in your dict definition (i assume the one right before `Truck`

Comment: How do *you* know that those are the values to be modified? Do you already have the new values in your dictionary before you read the file and see the old values? Or, do you have some way to check if a number should be modified as you read it?

Comment: @Blckknight Yes, I already have the new values in the dictionary. Essentially I am giving feeding the file (an input file) into a black box, reading the output, and then generating new parameters to modify the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. I create a generator that you can then iterate over to write your updated file.

```
def get_lines(dic):
    brand = ''
    model = ''
    parameter = ''
    with open('testinput.txt', 'r') as fil:
        for line in fil:
            if line[1:].strip().isdigit() and brand in dic and model in dic[brand] and parameter in dic[brand][model]:
                yield '&{0}\n'.format(dic[brand][model][parameter])
            elif line.startswith('&Brand:'):
                brand = line.split(': ')[-1].strip()
                yield line
            elif line.startswith('&Model:'):
                model= line.split(': ')[-1].strip()
                yield line
            elif line.startswith('&Parameter:'):
                parameter= line.split(': ')[-1].strip()
                yield line
            else:
                yield line

params = {'Ford': {'Sedan': {'Cost': 17000, 'Stock': 43}}, 'Honda':{'Sedan': {'Cost': 19000, 'Stock': 12}, 'Truck': {'Cost': 33000, 'Stock': 5}}}

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fil:
    for line in get_lines(params):
        fil.write(line)
```

Comment: except parameter lines take up many lines but +1 since a generator is a great idea

Comment: @JoranBeasley where do you see that parameter lines take up many lines?

Comment: in his example 3 lines per parameter name,type,value (type is noticably absent from his dictionary) ....

Comment: sure, i figured it was just a unit and that line will stay unchanged, am I wrong?

Comment: no I see what your doing now ... that works fine ( I gave you +1 even before ... since a generator is a very appropriate way to handle this problem)

Comment: @frthplnt i just edited my answer, because there were a few kinks but it is now tested and working. let me know if that is not what you are after.

Comment: @Julien Sorry for the delay, looks great! You are correct that the unit line stays unchanged, the format of the file itself is kind of weird, but it is out of my hands. I appreciate the help, I'm a little embarrassed how long I was throwing myself against this wall.

Answer (score 1):

Have to looked at Python's regular expressions? Take a look at the 're' package. You can use that to search for numerical entries. You can identify the lines of interest like this (from the top of my head and not checked):

```
import re
...
m = re.match(r'&(\d+)', the_line)
if m:
    print 'found ', m.group(1)
    # modify it...
```

The expression matches any number of digits (the \d+ part). Not sure if & is special, but if it is you can put in in square brackets.

Granted, You'll need similar regular expressions to capture that the line before is cost, and then capture the value. You can do that with a simple flag to signal net line is cost.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: that's an overkill ... `line.strip('&').isdigit()` or even `line[1:].isdigit()` tells you if it is a number or not

Answer (score 1):

You can read your line `while` reach a `\n\n` :

```
import re
model=''
brand=''
whit open('old_file') as f1,open('out_file','w') as f2:

    for line in f1:
          while line !='\n\n':
                if 'Brand' in line :
                    brand=re.match(r'&Brand:(.*)',line).group(1)
                    f2.write(line)
                elif 'Model' in line:
                    model=re.match(r'&Model:(.*)',line).group(1)
                    f2.write(line)

                elif model and brand:
                      if line.strip('&')=='Dollars':
                            f2.write('Dollars'+'\n'+params[brand.strip()][model.strip()]['Cost'])
                      elif line.strip('&')=='Quantity':
                            f2.write('Dollars'+'\n'+params[brand.strip()][model.strip()]['Stock'])

                else:
                      f2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re,fileinput
def print_new_data(brand,model,data):
    print "&Brand: %s"%(brand)
    print "&Define Class"
    print "&Model: %s"%(model)
    print "&Parameter: Cost"
    print "&Dollars"
    print "&%s"%data["cost"]
    print "&Parameter: Stock"
    print "&Quantity"
    print "&%s\n"%data["stock"]        

def process(fh):
    line = next(fh)
    brand= re.findall("Brand: (.*)",line)
    if not brand or brand[0] not in my_list_of_brands::
       print line
       return
    brand = brand[0]
    junk = next(fh)
    model_line = next(fh)
    model_name = re.findall("Model: (.*)",model_line)[0]
    if model_name not in my_data[brand]:
       print line
       print junk
       print model_line
       return
    while line.strip():
       next(fh)
    print_new_data(brand,model,my_data[brand][model])


fh = fileinput.open(["my_data_file"],inplace=1):
while True:
    process(fh)
```

dang ... I cant believe how much time i just wasted doing that for you ...

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of doing this sooner, but it makes so much more sense than trying to edit only a few things in line. Really appreciate your help!